# How to display from a post_type the first post and then to skip it in the next array

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to display posts from a post_type in a certain way: display the first post type withing a query then in the next query to skip that first post and show the second post and so on.

I've tried to do this with offset, the first post shows but the next one doesn't show. Is there a more elegant way to achive this?

```
        <div class="tableCell">
          <?php
          $args = array( 'post_type' => 'service', 'offset' => 1);  
          $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
          while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
          <div class="flip">
              <a href="#">
                  <div class="flip-front">
                      <div class="imgHolder">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flip-back">
                      <div class="imgHolder">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                  </div>
              </a>
          </div>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="tableCell">
          <?php
          $args = array( 'post_type' => 'service', 'offset' => 2);  
          $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
          while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
          <div class="flip">
              <a href="#">
                  <div class="flip-front">
                      <div class="imgHolder">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flip-back">
                      <div class="imgHolder">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                  </div>
              </a>
          </div>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for starters - its healthy to use the `wp_reset_postdata` when you have multiple `wp_queries` on one page.

in terms of your question. the first post type doesnt need an offset and your second one should offset 1 (minus the first)

```
<div class="tableCell">
          <?php
          $args = array( 'post_type' => 'service', 'posts_per_page' => 1);  
          $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
          while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
          <div class="flip">
              <a href="#">
                  <div class="flip-front">
                      <div class="imgHolder">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flip-back">
                      <div class="imgHolder">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                  </div>
              </a>
          </div>
          <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
<div class="tableCell">
          <?php
          $args2 = array( 'post_type' => 'service', 'offset' => 1);  
          $loop2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
          while ( $loop2->have_posts() ) : $loop2->the_post(); ?>
          <div class="flip">
              <a href="#">
                  <div class="flip-front">
                      <div class="imgHolder">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flip-back">
                      <div class="imgHolder">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                  </div>
              </a>
          </div>
          <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
```